# Javascript doesn't change appended content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So guys I've created some buttons that have to show different messages on click but after I click on one button also the others show the same message as it.
I'd also need some tips on how to make this section of my website responsive. 
Here is how the section looks like on the site: [image]

And here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/eLu2n6pj/1/

```js
var counter = 0;

$("#tasto1").click(function() {
  $("#blocco").animate({
    'opacity': '1'
  }, 500);

  if (counter <= 0) {
    $(".testo").append('<b name="grassetto">Test 1');
    counter++;
  }
});

$(function() {
  $('#tasto1').blur(function() {
    $('#blocco').animate({
      'opacity': '0'
    }, 500);
  });
});

$("#tasto2").click(function() {
  $("#blocco").animate({
    'opacity': '1'
  }, 500);
  if (counter <= 0) {

    $(".testo").append('Test 2');
    counter++;
  }
});

$(function() {
  $('#tasto2').blur(function() {
    $('#blocco').animate({
      'opacity': '0'
    }, 500);
  });
});

$("#tasto3").click(function() {
  $("#blocco").animate({
    'opacity': '1'
  }, 500);
  if (counter <= 0) {

    $(".testo").append('Test 3');
    counter++;
  }
});
```

```css
P {
  color: black;
}

#blocco {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #555;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
}

button[type="button"] {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  width: 270px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<section class="feature-area relative pt-100 pb-20" name="infobox">
  <div class="overlay overlay-bg"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" name="asppi">
        <div class="single-feature" name="testo">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <button id="tasto1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-placement="right">
              Button 1
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button id="tasto2" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-placement="right">
              Button 2
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button id="tasto3" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-placement="right">
              Button 3
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div id="blocco" class="single-feature">
          <p class="testo"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the purpose of counter?

Comment: The fiddle works, after the first click due to the counter all buttons are useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly fade in/out the text, you need to do something like this, where you change the text while the opacity is 0, or else it will flicker

With `animation` you can do that by insert a function, like this, and nest them, instead of using the `blur`

```
.animate({
'opacity': '0'}, 500, function() {
  $(".testo").html('<b name="grassetto">Test 1');
})
.animate({
'opacity': '1'}, 500);
```

In below sample I used `.html()` instead, to assign the new text.

I also temporarily removed the `if (counter <= 0) {...}` statement, as it is unclear what it is intended to accomplish

Stack snippet

```js
var counter = 0;

$("#tasto1").click(function() {
  $("#blocco")
    .animate({
    'opacity': '0'}, 500, function() {
      $(".testo").html('<b name="grassetto">Test 1');
    })
    .animate({
    'opacity': '1'}, 500);
  counter++;
});

$("#tasto2").click(function() {
  $("#blocco")
    .animate({
    'opacity': '0'}, 500, function() {
      $(".testo").html('<b name="grassetto">Test 2');
    })
    .animate({
    'opacity': '1'}, 500);
  counter++;
});

$("#tasto3").click(function() {
  $("#blocco")
    .animate({
    'opacity': '0'}, 500, function() {
      $(".testo").html('<b name="grassetto">Test 3');
    })
    .animate({
    'opacity': '1'}, 500);
  counter++;
});
```

```css
P {
  color: black;
}

#blocco {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #555;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
}

button[type="button"] {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  width: 270px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<section class="feature-area relative pt-100 pb-20" name="infobox">
  <div class="overlay overlay-bg"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" name="asppi">
        <div class="single-feature" name="testo">
          <ul>
            <li><button id="tasto1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-placement="right">
                                    Button 1
                                    </button></li>
            <li><button id="tasto2" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-placement="right">
                                   Button 2
                                    </button></li>
            <li><button id="tasto3" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-placement="right">
                                    Button 3
                                    </button></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div id="blocco" class="single-feature">
          <p class="testo"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I used the counter because everytime I clicked on the button the text was written other times but thanks your code works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending, change the content of `.testo` like this

```
$(".testo").html('<b name="grassetto">Test 1');
```

Also, the reason it only works on the first try is this `if-condition`

```
if (counter <= 0) {

    //
}
```

Get rid of that and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Change your javascript to this

```
 $("#tasto1").click(function() {
   $("#blocco").animate({
    'opacity': '1'
   }, 500);

    $(".testo").html('<b name="grassetto">Test 1');

});

$(function() {
   $('#tasto1').blur(function() {
     $('#blocco').animate({
       'opacity': '0'
      }, 500);
    });
 });

 $("#tasto2").click(function() {
    $("#blocco").animate({
    'opacity': '1'
    }, 500);

     $(".testo").html('Test 2');

   });

$(function() {
  $('#tasto2').blur(function() {
    $('#blocco').animate({
      'opacity': '0'
    }, 500);
  });
});

$("#tasto3").click(function() {
  $("#blocco").animate({
    'opacity': '1'
  }, 500);

    $(".testo").html('Test 3');

 });
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of what you've changed?

Comment: removed the counter if condition and instead of appending used .html() to add the element

Answer (score 1):

From a conceptual level, in the case when you have to replace the inner HTML inside an HTML Element, you use `.html()`. In the case when you have to append to the end of the existing HTML Element, you use `.append()`.

Usage of `append` is incorrect in your use case, as you are replacing the contents of the element to which the class `testo` has been assigned after the button is clicked.

If you replace `.append()` with `.html()`, your code should work fine.